# Put values parsed from JSONResponse to global array swift 3

Tags: ios, parsing, swift3, alamofire

How to use values globally parsed from JSONResponse. So, far able to extract the array from JSONResponse, but after that trying to put that array in an global array, not getting how to declare global array. somehow managed to do that but now not able to extract values index wise from that array. Please guide.

Code tried now:

```
if (JSONResponse["status"].intValue == 1)
        {

            if let fetchedImages = JSONResponse["data"].arrayObject {
                self.arrResponseReceived = fetchedImages
            }
            print("self.arrResponseReceived", self.arrResponseReceived)
        }
        else
        {
            CommonMethodsClass.showAlertMessage(vc: self, titleStr: "Error!", messageStr: strMsg)
        }
```

Code tried earlier:

```
arrResponseReceived = JSONResponse["data"].arrayValue
```

Global variable declared for array is:

```
var arrResponseReceived : [Any] = []
```

Data to parse is:

```
  {
    data =     (
                {
            AverageRating = 4;
            Image = "<null>";
            IsActive = 1;
            Latitude = "28.567806";
            Longitude = "77.3236273";
            SalonAddress = " Sec-58, India";
            SalonEmail = "vy.chan@th-rce.com";
            SalonID = 1;
            SalonImage = "";
            SalonMobile = 9999888877;
            SalonName = Affinity;
            SalonPhone = 9999888877;
            TimeIntervalminutes = 20;
        },
                {
            AverageRating = 5;
            Image = "<null>";
            IsActive = 1;
            Latitude = "";
            Longitude = "";
            SalonAddress = "Mall, India";
            SalonEmail = "rad@th-rce.com";
            SalonID = 3;
            SalonImage = "";
            SalonMobile = 9999888877;
            SalonName = Looks;
            SalonPhone = 9999888877;
            TimeIntervalminutes = 30;
        }
    );
    message = "";
    status = 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you don't know how create global array for the project? And how access values from this?

Comment: i am getting values in it self.arrResponseReceived[1] but when i use self.arrResponseReceived[1]["name"]. It gives error type 'Any' has no subscript members.

Comment: how you declare `self.arrResponseReceived` array?

Comment: Why do you use such an unspecified type like `[Any]`? The received type is clearly `[[String:Any]]`. The goal of Swift's strong type system is to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should definite the Class of what is inside of JSONResponse["data"].arrayValue, or how Xcode knows it.
If you want to get an data array which is made of Dictionary , here is how I cheated it out.

```
func getDatas(from json: Any?) -> [Dictionary] {
    guard let json = json as? NSDictionary, let entries = json.value(forKeyPath: "data") as? [NSDictionary] else {
        return []
    }

    return entries.flatMap { entry in
        guard let dictionary = entry as? NSDictionary else {
            return nil
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

you call it as such

```
self.arrResponseReceived = getDatas(from: json)
```

NSDictionary has the method value(forKeyPath:) that is near magic. Calling json.value(forKeyPath: "data") returns an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary is an "entry" object in the json. Next, I map each entry  which returns a dictionary.

If this is something more than a quick solution, then I would consider adding SwiftyJSON to your project.

```
func getDatas(from json: Any?) -> [Dicitonary] {
    return JSON(json)["data"].arrayValue.flatMap { entry in
        guard let dictionary = entry as? NSDictionary else {
            return nil
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```